# How do I run this program in an applet?

Tags: java, applet, console-application

```
package Homework;

import java.util.Scanner;

class FantasyGame{

    public static void main ( String args[])

    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious Quest!");
        System.out.println("Enter the name of your character: ");
        String name;
        name = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Welcome to Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious Quest, " + (name) + "! " + "You will now assign attributes to your character, the total value assigned must not exceed 15 or be under 0, or the points will be assigned by default! (Type any NUMBER to continue)");
        int ans = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Strength (0-15): ");
        int str = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Health (0-15): ");
        int hp = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Luck (0-15): ");
        int lck = scan.nextInt();
        if (str + hp + lck <= 15)
        {
        System.out.println("Congratulations! You have successfully created your character!");
        System.out.println("Name: " + (name));
        System.out.println("Strength: " + (str));
        System.out.println("Health: " + (hp));
        System.out.println("Luck: " + (lck));
        }

        if (str + hp + lck > 15)
        {
        System.out.println("You have give your character too many attribute points! Default values have been assigned.");
        System.out.println("Name: " + (name));
        System.out.println("Strength: " + (5));
        System.out.println("Health: " + (5));
        System.out.println("Luck: " + (5));
        }


    }

}
```

I want to make a text-based game for my history class and I know basic Java enough to make a small one with just variables and stuff but I don't know how I can make it so that it runs directly as an applet with a black background and white text that shows up and responds to what you type, like the code above does in the console.

I've tried the command prompt method but all I get is "Access is Denied."

Also, when I try to export in eclipse, the launch configuration always goes to a class I don't want. Sorry but I am really confused and need a lot of help on this.

Comment: have you ever written applets before? they're not the same as writing a simple class that has to run using a main method

Comment: No, is there any way I could run a program like this in a text-based game applet though?

Comment: Is your game going online? I'm sure I'm able to cheat your stats attribute system by setting my stats to have 3 extremely high stats looking @ your source code.

Comment: Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Answer (score 1):

to write a simple applet, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/ this tutorial from oracle will walk you through it fairly well, it shouldn't be too hard to rearrange your code then

Comment: How would I convert the .java file to an .exe?

Comment: that's a whole other question, and for the applet I'm not sure if you need to, but you'd package your application in a jar, when you compile, with a manifest file declaring the java file with the main method, but as I said that's a whole other question

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I just exported my program as a .jar and used Jar2Exe and it worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have not made you class **public** and that is why you are getting error "Access is denied" because it is not visible any more. Compiler is not able to find that class. Just write

```
....
//change is here 
public class FantasyGame
{
....
}
....
```

Thanks !